# Find Larger subnet(one with less contiguous 1's) between the two

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a code snippet that finds the larger subnet between the two subnet masks. The code snippet uses left shift operators and IMHO makes code unreadable(maybe because I have rarely used it, and I believe a lot of developers do not make use of it nowadays).

Here is the code doing the job.

```
        IPAddress subNet1 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
        IPAddress subNet2 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.128.0");

        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = subNet1.GetAddressBytes();
        int tempSub1 = Convert.ToInt32((bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3]));

        bytes = subNet2.GetAddressBytes();
        int tempSub2 = Convert.ToInt32((bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3]));

        if(tempSub1 == tempSub2)
            Console.WriteLine("Pick Any Subnet");

        //Find Larger Subnet(Less number of contiguous 1's)
        if(tempSub1<tempSub2)
            Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 is Larget Subnet");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Subnet 2 is Larget Subnet");
```

Another way I can think of is; for the readability sake
convert IP address to Binary, store the values in strings and then compare 1's.

What are the ways to make the code more understandable(for people who are not used to shift operators)?

Comment: Re "*Is there another elegant way of doing this job?*", That implies converting to binary is elegant. It's not. Keep what you have.

Comment: Or if you don't actually need the subnet, just compare the bytes.

Comment: I am sorry for my English, I am not used to seeing shift operators and understanding the code seems to a problem at first glance.

Comment: Then use better var names. If you named your var `subnetMask2` instead of `tempSub2`, you wouldn't have to work through the equation to figure out what the code does.

Comment: Let me see if I got your point correctly, you are suggesting.
1. Go with shift operators. Even though they are not frequently used.
2. Improve naming?

Comment: I am having hard time digesting `(bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3])` line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the appropriate way of converting the bytes into an integer. However, `BitConverter` can hide the nastiness away.

```
IPAddress subnet1 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
IPAddress subnet2 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.128.0");

int subnet1Mask = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(subnet1.GetAddressBytes(), 0));
int subnet2Mask = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(subnet2.GetAddressBytes(), 0));

int cmp = -subnet1Mask.CompareTo(subnet2Mask);
if      (cmp < 0) { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 is smaller than Subnet 2."); }
else if (cmp > 0) { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 is larger than Subnet 2."); }
else              { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 and Subnet 2 have the same size."); }
```

That said, you could simply compare the array of bytes instead of converting into an integer at all.

```
int compareSubnetSize(IPAddress subnet1, IPAddress subnet2)
{
    byte[] subnet1MaskBytes = subnet1.GetAddressBytes();
    byte[] subnet2MaskBytes = subnet2.GetAddressBytes();

    int cmp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        cmp = subnet1MaskBytes[i].CompareTo(subnet2MaskBytes[i]);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return -cmp;
    }

    return 0;
}

IPAddress subnet1 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
IPAddress subnet2 = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.128.0");

int cmp = compareSubnetSize(subnet1, subnet2);
if      (cmp < 0) { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 is smaller than Subnet 2."); }
else if (cmp > 0) { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 is larger than Subnet 2."); }
else              { Console.WriteLine("Subnet 1 and Subnet 2 have the same size."); }
```

Comment: Lacks the error checking that my answer had, but since mine got downvoted to hell I'll upvote yours.  You do have a typo though, `bytes[]` should be `byte[]`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing IPv4 addresses as strings seems easier than converting them. For example:

```
Regex.Replace("255.255.255.0", @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(3))       //  "255.255.255.  0"

string.Concat("255.255.255.0".Split('.').Select(s => s.PadLeft(4)))   // " 255 255 255   0"

BitConverter.ToString(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0").GetAddressBytes())  // "FF-FF-FF-00"

string.Concat("255.255.255.0".Split('.').Select(s => $"{int.Parse(s):X2}")))  // "FFFFFF00"
```